# simple python text adventure game errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this sample rpg text adventure game online and im trying to understand the codes so that i can use it as a reference to develop my own text adventure game in the future. However, i am currently facing the error "gold is not defined at line 121 and i suspect is cause by indentation error. Although this is the error im facing so far, i believed that are more mistakes in the codes which i am glad for anyone to point it out.Thanks!

```
# gold = int(100)
inventory = ["sword", "armor", "potion"]

print("Welcome hero")
name = input("What is your name: ")
print("Hello", name,)
# role playing program
#
# spend 30 points on strenght, health, wisdom, dexterity 
# player can spend and take points from any attribute

classic = {"Warrior",
         "Archer",
         "Mage",
         "Healer"}
print("Choose your race from", classic,)
classicChoice = input("What class do you choose: ")
print("You are now a", classicChoice,)


# library contains attribute and points
attributes = {"strenght": int("0"),
             "health": "0",
             "wisdom": "0",
             "dexterity": "0"}

pool = int(30)
choice = None
print("The Making of a Hero !!!")
print(attributes)
print("\nYou have", pool, "points to spend.")

while choice != "0":
    # list of choices
    print(
    """
    Options: 

    0 - End
    1 - Add points to an attribute
    2 - remove points from an attribute
    3 - Show attributes
    """
    )
    choice = input("Choose option: ")
    if choice == "0":
        print("\nYour hero stats are:")
        print(attributes)
    elif choice == "1":
        print("\nADD POINTS TO AN ATTRIBUTE")
        print("You have", pool, "points to spend.")
        print(
        """
        Choose an attribute:
           strenght
           health
           wisdom
           dexterity
        """
        )
        at_choice = input("Your choice: ")
        if at_choice.lower() in attributes:
            points = int(input("How many points do you want to assign: "))
            if points <= pool:
                pool -= points
                result = int(attributes[at_choice]) + points
                attributes[at_choice] = result
                print("\nPoints have been added.")
            else:
                print("\nYou do not have that many points to spend")
        else:
            print("\nThat attribute does not exist.")
    elif choice == "2":
        print("\nREMOVE POINTS FROM AN ATTRIBUTE")
        print("You have", pool, "points to spend.")
        print(
        """
        Choose an attribute:
           strenght
           health
           wisdom
           dexterity
        """
        )
        at_choice = input("Your choice: ")
        if at_choice.lower() in attributes:
            points = int(input("How many points do you want to remove: "))
            if points <= int(attributes[at_choice]):
                pool += points
                result = int(attributes[at_choice]) - points
                attributes[at_choice] = result
                print("\nPoints have been removed.")
            else:
                print("\nThere are not that many points in that attribute")
        else:
            print("\nThat attribute does not exist.")

    elif choice == "3":
        print("\n", attributes)
        print("Pool: ", pool)
    else:
        print(choice, "is not a valid option.")





While True:
print("Here is your inventory: ", inventory)
print("What do you wish to do?")
print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")

crossbow = int(50)
spell = int(35)
potion = int(35)


if choice == "shop":
    print("Welcome to the shop!")
    print("You have", gold,"gold")
    buy = input("What would you like to buy? A crossbow, a spell or a potion: ")

    if buy == "crossbow":
        print("this costs 50 gold")
        answer = input("Do you want it: ")
        if answer == "yes":
            print("Thank you for coming!")
            inventory.append("crossbow")
            gold = gold - crossbow
            print("Your inventory is now:")
            print(inventory)
            print("Your gold store now is: ", gold)
        if answer == "no":
            print("Thank you for coming!")

    if buy == "spell":
        print("this costs 35 gold")
        answear2 = input("Do you want it: ")
        if answear2 == "yes":
            print("Thank you for coming!")
            inventory.append("spell")
            gold = gold - spell
            print("Your inventory is now:")
            print(inventory)
        if answear2 == "no":
            print("Thank you for coming!")


    if buy == "potion":
        print("this costs 35 gold")
        answear3 = input("Do you want it: ")
        if answear3 == "yes":
            print("Thank you for coming!")
            inventory.append("spell")
            gold = gold - potion
            print("Your inventory is now:")
            print(inventory)
        if answear3 == "no":
            print("Thank you for coming!")


choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")
while choice != "shop" or "tavern" or "forest":
    print("Not acepted")
    print("What do you wish to do?")
    print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
    choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")

if choice == "teavern":
    print("You enter the tavern and see a couple of drunken warriors singing, a landlord behind the bar and a dodgy figure sitting at the back of the tavern.")
    tavernChoice = input("Would you like to talk to the 'drunken warriors', to the 'inn keeper', approach the 'dodgy figure' or 'exit'")

    if tavernChoice == "drunken warriors":
        print("You approach the warriors to greet them.")
        print("They notice you as you get close and become weary of your presence.")
        print("As you arrive at their table one of the warriors throughs a mug of ale at you.")
    if dexterity >= 5:
        print("You quickly dodge the mug and leave the warriors alone")
    else:
        print("You are caught off guard and take the mug to the face compleatly soaking you.")
        print("The dodgy figure leaves the tavern")
```

Comment: It might help if the code in your question was a [mre] for the problem you are asking about, with the extraneous code removed.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: In addition to creating a Minimal Reproducible Example, also realize that grammar, punctuation, readability are important, as specified in the How to Ask links above.  It also shows attention to detail, and shows you value the time volunteers give to you freely, as you put time into posting your question, and making it easy to read and understand, and that you put your own time into solving your question before and while reaching out. Please `edit` your question so it can be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance at it. `#gold = int(100)` is commented out on line 1.
This causes a issue because it doesn't know what gold is. it isn't defined. remove the # before it.